# How to merge two $(document).ready(function() in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script src="jQuery/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>



$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#myTable").tablesorter({

    });

    $("#accordion").accordion({ 
        autoHeight: false, collapsible: true, active: false
    });



});
```

...

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h3><a href="#">First header</a></h3>
    <div>First content</div>
    <h3><a href="#">Second header</a></h3>
    <div>Second content</div>
</div>

<table border =1 cellpadding =8 id="myTable" class="tablesorter" WIDTH="80%">
<thead>
<th><h3> Date </h3></th>
<th><h3> Report </h3></th>
</thead><tbody>
<tr>
<td>row 1, cell 1</td>
<td>row 1, cell 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>row 2, cell 1</td>
<td>row 2, cell 2</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Comment: I only see one `$(document).ready(function() { ... })` in your example.

Comment: I mean I can only get tablesorter to work, or accordion.

Comment: Are you throwing any javascript errors? javascript stops execution when an unhandled error is encountered.

Comment: Could we get your html as well as showing us where you put your scripts?

Comment: additionally it would be a good idea to include links tot he libraries you are using. Obviously jQuery is a given but tablesorter and accordian are likely plugins or part of the jQuery UI framework.

Comment: Also not seeing an errors, maybe they are just incompatible?

Comment: @RVWard, you can have as many functions inside `$(document).ready(function()` as you want. You can even have multiple `$(document).ready(function()`'s. It's worth pointing out that`$(function()` is shorthand.

Comment: @RWard. Have you tried loading your tablesorter script AFTER loading jQuery script

Comment: @Ben, that is the only way it worked, I had to separate them and then make them into two separate functions... Weird. Then Tablesorter had to come after jQuery.

Comment: Why did I get marked down? I was trying to get you my HTML but it is full of irrelevant stuff, I am sure you don't want hundreds of lines of code.

Comment: Try adding some text to your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tablesorter needs to load after jquery

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <script src="jQuery/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Just a note anything that uses jquery must be loaded after jquery is loaded